# Tuple to CSV file

Tags: python

Im trying to play around with writing a tuple to a csv file with each element on a newline.

So far it look like this:

```
import csv
import platform


if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    newline=''
else:
    newline=None

test = ("apple", "banana", "cherry")

def write_list_to_file(output_file, lst):
    with open(output_file, 'w', newline=newline) as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(lst)
    print("File created")
    
write_list_to_file("test.csv", test)
```

How ever the output in the file loks like this:

a,p,p,l,e

b,a,n,a,n,a

c,h,e,r,r,y

Why does i end up with commas inbetween and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerows()` expects a 2D array or rows and columns, i.e. a list of 2 iterables. You accidentally have that: the tuple is iterable, giving 3 rows. The words are iterable, giving a character each.

But that's not what you want. It seems to me you want a single line with the words separated by commas. To achieve that, you need to put the tuple into a list:

```
write_list_to_file("test.csv", [test])
```

That way it will iterate over the list, giving 1 row and then iterate over the tuple giving 3 words.

If you want 3 individual lines, you need to put each word into an iterable (tuple or array):

```
test = (["apple"], ["banana"], ["cherry"])
```

or

```
test = (("apple",) , ("banana",) , ("cherry",))
```

Comment: However that gives the output on one line (apple,banana,cherry), therefor i might aswell just use writerow() but i want the output like this:
apple
banana
cherry each on a new line